# How to pass unichar object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I need to pass a character to the line no. 2: First method I tried,

```
1) unichar dicttxt = [[myword lowercaseString] characterAtIndex:0];

   2) fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:dicttxt ofType: @"txt"];
```

2nd Method I tried,

```
NSString *dicttxt = [[myword lowercaseString] characterAtIndex:0];

fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:dicttxt ofType: @"txt"];
```

Both method suggest error `Make pointer from integer without a cast.`

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not using NSString?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using a character, use:

```
NSString *dicttxt = [[myword lowercaseString] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:dicttxt ofType:@"txt"];
```

Alternatively (and I forget about this method entirely), the following is functionally equivalent to the above, but more concise:

```
NSString *dicttxt = [[myword lowercaseString] substringToIndex:1];
fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:dicttxt ofType:@"txt"];
```

These will work as long as:

1. `myword` has a length of at least 1.
2. `myword` does not start with composite characters (i.e. “café” is fine, but “über” might not be).

Answer (score 1):

Dreamlax’s answer is correct, but it doesn’t address the reason for your problem: `unichar` is not a class, and there is no such thing as a `unichar` object. If you command-double-click `unichar` in Xcode, it shows you the declaration:

```
typedef unsigned short unichar;
```

In other words, `unichar` is an alias to the primitive integer type `unsigned short`.